# Do certain laptops, say Macbooks, have significantly better hardware buses than others?

Tags: memory, cpu, speed, gpu, bus

Many modern laptops do not allow one to change the memory banks, as they are welded in, especially ultrabooks and Macbooks seem to have this 'feature'. I've heard that sometimes this idea is beneficial for performance, especially when memory is not just welded on but actually a part of the CPU. However, I have not been able to verify this as truth, possible due to my lack of in-depth hardware knowledge.

Making an ancient comparison between mac and not-mac laptops, I dug up these two devices as an example:

http://us.hardware.info/productinfo/201150/apple-macbook-pro-15q-me293na

http://us.hardware.info/productinfo/202040/asus-n550jv-cn270h

The Macbook is overall better, as it has a much higher resolution screen, has an SSD, has less weight and maybe it also has better battery power. Consider that the HDD of the ASUS was replaced with a SSD and consider that both run the same OS, for example some version of linux. Also imagine that I am doing some computational task, for example in Matlab or some simulation that either uses the CPU or GPU, and which can be run in parallel easily.

Does apple do "magical" stuff in how they weld or mount the hardware? Does the ASUS need more time to get 8 bytes out of memory to the CPU or GPU, than the apple? Does apple have faster hardware buses? Does the apple machine has a computational advantage compared to the ASUS? Is there some kind of fast GPU-CPU buss that the ASUS does not have? Or can I just assume that if the CPU, GPU, RAM and disk are the same or similar, speed from a hardware point of view will also be more or less the same?

**Summarized: are there other things to look at then just CPU-model, GPU-model, RAM-amount and type and disk read/write speeds to estimate a laptops general computational capacity?**

Comment: Apple uses the same GPU and Intel parts everyone else does. They might put a better display but the hardware itself is identical to nearly identical models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term to for 'welding' components on to printed circuit boards is called soldering.

Broadly speaking, a soldered connection is much better than a contact connection because it is almost a continuous conductor.  Contacts can introduce interference into an electrical signals, particularly if the contact points are dirty.

To answer your question about Apple's 'bus' vs Acer's bus.  The buses and interconnects at the component level are all pretty much industry standard, PCI, PCIe, USB, DDR, etc.  This does not mean that circuit boards (PCBs) are interchangeable, as these are heavily customised to suit the manufactures design aims, manufacturing processes, and increasingly temperature management.

Temperature/Thermal management is quite a bit easier to design for if components are mounted, and will not change, but then the ability to expand is compromised.

I am not going to get into a comparison of the two systems that you mentioned, if you have a particular about the two devices, then please state it directly.

> Summarized: are there other things to look at then just CPU-model, GPU-model, RAM-amount and type and disk read/write speeds to estimate a laptops general computational capacity?

Yes, you could also look for/at weight, battery life, screen size, hard drive, optical disk,   style, docking station, keyboard, number and type of external ports.  All these have impact on price of the computer.

You need to consider carefully what your objectives with what you want to do and achieve with your computer, and shop around accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the summarized question was meant w.r.t speed of calculations, not in general. Could you comment on that? So basically, yes I am interested in whether the macbook would suit those needs better than the ASUS, given the similar specs on CPU,GPU and RAM, but tried to make the question as generic as possible to also benefit other readers.

Comment: Thermal management: the ability of the computer to get rid of heat quickly and efficiently.  Notebook cooling pads help.  Modern CPU'S will slow themselves down if they they get too hot.  Newer CPU's are much more resilient to heat.  Also the type and version of the storage system: SATA or SATA2, and HDD vs SSD.  I don't think there are any laptops that use SAS as a storage interface.

Comment: Fair enough, I want a fast (SSD) disk just to have a fast OS (during boot and usage), most of the calculations I do fit in memory and hence slow disks won't influence them much. I think I am mostly looking at fast CPU-GPU-RAM interaction. Would you say the Macbook is significantly faster because it stays cooler?

Comment: No, I think premium laptops all are perform roughly the same. An i5 Apple will perform similarly to an i5 Toshiba Tecra or Portege, so long as they are using the same CPU chip version.  I do think the Mac OSX is better than Windows 8.

Comment: Hah, yes, I left the operating systems out of the scope :) I prefer linux, especially since it has better package management (that is, ubuntu has), and since I know it a lot better than Macintosh. However, I would expect that calculations as aforementioned perform similar on a Macbook with either linux or Macintosh. May I conclude that you would say the two laptops I mentioned are similar 'premium laptops' (except for disk, screen, weight and battery)?

Comment: Yes, if you need the retina type display, I think Apple is the only game in town.  If you are going to reload linux onto it, I would see what other manufactures have.  My girlfriend wanted a Mac, but got a very nice 4th generation i7 HP for £800.  The comparable Mac was at least £1200+